# How can I filter core data based records to avoid the appearance of duplicates. (Swift 4)

Tags: core-data, swift3

I am pulling records from a core data entity. The records each contain "brand", "model", "size", and "price". There are various size and cost options.

I want to see unique records of "brand" and "model". As you can see from the screenshot, that is not working.

This is a code snip I've written so far:

```
 let sortDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor!
        let defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if defaults.integer(forKey: "sequenceSwitchValue") == 0 {
            sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "brand", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))
        } else {
            sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "brand", ascending: false, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))
        }


         let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: filmEntity)
        request.returnsDistinctResults = true
        request.propertiesToFetch = ["brand", "model"]

        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        request.predicate = nil

        do {
            films = try context.fetch(request) as! [FilmEntity]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error While Fetching Data From DB: \(error.userInfo)")
        }
```

[image]

Comment: If brand and model together constitute a unique object in your mind, you have designed your data model incorrectly. Start over with a to-many relationship between the brand-model entity and the size entity.

Comment: light bulb > on. Thanks